# Implementation of Blockchain on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containers

My team is currently working on how to implement blockchain on Kubernetes. We have around five application drivers, namely Reader, Writer, Processor etc., which does their own task. Each one of them is a sperate Docker image. On the other hand, we have deployed one master node and 3 worker nodes in the cloud server. So my doubts are:

1. Do we need more than three K8s nodes?
2. Is it feasible or even possible to apply blockchain on K8s in the long run?
3. As the number of user increases, can we scale the nodes without downtime?

Thanks in advance for any feedbacks and suggestions.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor?

Comment: Its from the cloud. It involves installing Kubespray, Terraform and Ansible